# Specifying the default value in widgets generated by pyviz hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, pyviz

I've got a 4D dataset and `hvplot` is nicely generating widgets for the dimensions I've specified in the `groupby`:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('http://gamone.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/coawst_4/use/fmrc/coawst_4_use_best.ncd')

rho_vars = ['salt','temp']

from cartopy import crs as ccrs
import hvplot.xarray
import holoviews as hv
from geoviews import tile_sources as gvts
import panel as pn

var_select = pn.widgets.Select(name='Variables:', options=rho_vars, 
                               value='temp')

crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

def plot(var=None):
    base_map = gvts.OSM
    var = var or var_select.value
    mesh = ds[var][-24:,:,:].hvplot.quadmesh(x='lon_rho', y='lat_rho', rasterize=True, title=var,
                                    width=600, height=400, crs=crs,
                                    groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]), cmap='jet')
    overlay = (base_map * mesh.opts(alpha=0.7)).opts(active_tools=['wheel_zoom', 'pan'])
    widgets = {dim: pn.widgets.Select for dim in ds[var].dims[:-2]}
    return pn.holoviews.HoloViews(overlay, widgets=widgets).layout

def on_var_select(event):
    var = event.obj.value
    dashboard[-1] = plot(var=var)

var_select.param.watch(on_var_select, parameter_names=['value']);

dashboard = pn.Column(var_select, plot(var_select.value))
```

which produces:

[image]

However, while `hvplot` defaults to the first value of the `options` `OrderedDict`, I would like to default to the last value.

If I look at the dashboard elements:

```
print(dashboard)

Column
    [0] Select(name='Variables:', options=OrderedDict([('salt', ...]), value='temp')
    [1] Row
        [0] HoloViews(DynamicMap, widgets={'time': <class 'panel.wid...})
        [1] Column
            [0] Select(name='Forecast time f..., options=OrderedDict([('2019-03-09 ...]), value=numpy.datetime64('2019-03-...)
            [1] Select(name='S-coordinate a..., options=OrderedDict([('-0.96875', ...]), value=-0.96875)
```

I see that I can specify the `Select` widget value *post facto* like:

```
dashboard[1][1][1].value = next(reversed(dashboard[1][1][1].options.values()))
```

and that indeed works:

[image]

I would like to make a stand alone dashboard, however, that defaults to a last value when the user selects a new variable.  With the current code, when a new variable is selected, the default value is unfortunately again set to the first value.

Is there a way to embed my *post facto* code to select the last value into my plot function, or is there another better approach to accomplish this?

[Full notebook here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/edb9eb572058c4fdee6708359d24539d).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, [the 'fields' argument](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/default-value-for-widgets/668) to hvplot can do this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you `print(dashboard)` you have a default value of widgets.

```
Column
    [0] Select(name='Variables:', options=OrderedDict([('salt', ...]), value='temp')
    [1] Row
        [0] HoloViews(DynamicMap, widgets={'time': <class 'panel.wid...})
        [1] Column
            [0] Select(name='Forecast time f..., options=OrderedDict([('2019-03-09 ...]), value=numpy.datetime64('2019-03-...)
            [1] Select(name='S-coordinate a..., options=OrderedDict([('-0.96875', ...]), value=-0.96875)
```

Here, the default value is `-0.96875` for the second widget.

I would work on this line `widgets = {dim: pn.widgets.Select for dim in ds[var].dims[:-2]}` to put default value.

```
default_value = [...,...]
widgets = {dim: pn.widgets.Select(value=default_val[dim]) for dim in ds[var].dims[:-2]}
```

Comment: Thomas, this seems like the right track, but when I specify  `Select(value=` all the other parameters like `Select(name=, options=` are lost.  It's frustrating!

Comment: Worth opening an issue for this in panel, we should consider finding a nice way to specify this. I'm not sure if modifying widgets a user constructed would be the best approach even it would be convenient in this case.